# How can I apply the same formatting command to the bibliography heading as for all other section headings?

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, formatting

I have been given a template that applies the same formatting command to all sections. I now added a bibliography and want the title of it to be formatted the same way. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor,biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Test,
    author = {Test, A},
    title = {What a test}
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\headingformatting}[1]{\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{orange}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax}
#1
\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}

\headingformatting{\section{Test}}
Here I am citing \cite{Test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Please ignore the fact, that my `\headingformatting` is typographically not appeasing. I just wanted to show how the document looks from a technical point of view.

Comment: I'm not sure about the use case of your template, but surely in the example the best solution to this would be to use KOMA-Script features to make sure that `\section` is typeset as desired without having to invoke `\headingformatting` for each `\section` manually.

Comment: @moewe I agree and would change that in the future, but as of now I quickly had to add a bibliography to an existing file, so  I didn‘t want to break anything by fiddling around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the best solution to this would be to use KOMA-Script features to make sure that `\section` is typeset as desired without having to invoke `\headingformatting` for each `\section` manually.

Since I don't know how to do that, here is the `biblatex` workaround that defines a new heading style that also applies `\headingformatting` for `\section`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor,biblatex}

\defbibheading{myheading}[\refname]{\headingformatting{\section{#1}}}

\newcommand{\headingformatting}[1]{\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{orange}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax}
#1
\end{minipage}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\headingformatting{\section{Test}}
Here I am citing \cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[heading=myheading]
\end{document}
```

[image: References header highlighted in the same way as "Test"]

The definition shown here is based on `\section`. If you want an unnumbered style, you can go for something like

```
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{myheading}[\refname]{%
  \headingformatting{\section*{#1}}%
  \@mkboth{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{myheading}[\refname]{%
  \headingformatting{\section*{#1}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \@mkboth{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

This should works.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor,biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Test,
    author = {Test, A},
    title = {What a test}
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\headingformatting}[1]{\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{orange}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax}
#1
\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}

\headingformatting{\section{Test}}
Here I am citing \cite{Test}

\printbibliography[title=\headingformatting{\refname}]

\end{document}
```